# Simple calculator-type program. Use of unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#

I'm only a couple of weeks into programming and thought I'd just have some fun and write a small calculator type console application. But, I seem to have hit a problem that I can't understand. I'm getting an error when trying to run the program that 'answer' is an unassigned local variable, but I'm pretty sure it's not??? It's on the 'answer' in the last Console.WriteLine();

I've double checked everything is spelled the same, including the same case.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int firstNumber, secondNumber, answer;
        string op;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
        firstNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a second number:");
        secondNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an op +, -, x, or /");
            op = Console.ReadLine();

            if (op != "+" || op != "-" || op != "x" || op != "/")
            {
                i += -1;
                Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
            }
        }

        if (op == "+")
            answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        else if (op == "-")
            answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        else if (op == "x")
            answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        else if (op == "/")
            answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        else
            answer = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

EDIT: The "please chose an op" line should have been in the loop. Fixed above.

The exact error message is now (having moved the above WriteLine)

> Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'op'

That seems to have replaced the last error message which said the same about 'answer'. 'op' is underlined in the first **if** statement.

The errors appear when I click "start" in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013 Express

Comment: If you are reading once the operator, why the loop?

Comment: The code as written does not produce the error message described.  In fact, it can never escape the for loop under any circumstances, much less reach the `Console.Writeline()`.

Comment: @Habib: The linked question/answer is not the same issue.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, you are right, From the first look, it looked like the dupe. I have reopened it but this should be closed, because I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: You get that error when you try to run it, or when you try to compile it?

Comment: Please post your exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is being generated during the compilation of your program (not the execution of it). Depending on how you write your `for` loop the body may or may not execute. The compiler doesn't analyze to try and figure that out, and just assumes the body might not execute. If the body weren't to execute, the code below would be referencing an uninitialized local variable. You either must initialize the variable (typically where you declare it), or use a different looping construct. As an example, you could use this:

```
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an op +, -, x, or /");
            op = Console.ReadLine();
            if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "x" || op == "/") break;
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
        }
```

In this code, the compiler knows that the body of the loop must execute at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (op != "+" && op != "-" && op != "x" && op != "/")
        {
            i += -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again");
        }
    }
```

But, why would you write it like that?